# How to create a controller in a Cocoa MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, qtkit

I want to build a Cocoa application using the Model-View-Controller design pattern.
I have a view subclassing QTMovieView that handles the keyDown event. 
I want to create a controller with several methods like setRate, getTime, but I don't know exactly how to connect it together. Can you give me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had element of answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222111/in-mvc-where-do-you-put-references-to-your-model-classes).
My QTMovieView (the view) has a reference to the AppDelegate (my controller). 
My controller contains the setRate, getTime, etc... method and transmit it to my movie object (the model).